# How would java interact with OpenGL?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

LWJGL is a wrapper for opengl for java. But how does it wrap? Does it somehow invoke c++ functions in the opengl.dll? Are the functions in opengl.dll even c++?

Comment: You can look at the code here: [sourceforge.net/projects/java-game-lib/](http://sourceforge.net/projects/java-game-lib/)

Comment: OpenGL API is usually in C, so LWJGL just wraps it by calling native methods.

Comment: @matias could you elaborate? I don't know what "native methods" are and how they are invoked.

Comment: @BlazArt You should look up JNI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JMonkey engine should support open GL 2 trough 4 
http://jmonkeyengine.org/

Comment: This is not the type of answer I am looking for.